# Is it true that $\int_{0}^{z}(1-f(\frac{\log D}{\log t} - 1))d(\frac{\log z}{\log t})^k = s^{-k}\int_{0}^{s}(1 - f(u))du^k$?

Tags: integration, analysis

Suppose we have an integral $\int_{0}^{z}(1-f(\frac{\log D}{\log t} - 1))d(\frac{\log z}{\log t})^k$.

Here the following are fixed constants $D > 0$, $s > 0$ and $z = D^{\frac{1}{s}}$ and $k > 0$. $f$ is a continuous function, monotonically increasing, $0 \leq f(s) < 1$ and satisfying $f(s) = 1 + O(e^{-s})$ as $s \rightarrow \infty$.

Let $u = \frac{\log D}{\log t}$ and so the integral transforms to $s^{-k}\int_{a}^{b}(1 - f(u))du^k$ however I am not sure what the new limits of integration $a$ and $b$ should be.

Part of my confusion is whether the old limits of integration in: $\int_{0}^{z}(1-f(\frac{\log D}{\log t} - 1))d(\frac{\log z}{\log t})^k$  are values of $t$ or values of $(\frac{\log z}{\log t})^k$.

My instinct tells me the integrand is a function of $t$ and therefore $b = \log D / \log z = s$ and $a = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \log D / \log t = 0$. Therefore is the following should be true:

$\int_{0}^{z}(1-f(\frac{\log D}{\log t} - 1))d(\frac{\log z}{\log t})^k = s^{-k}\int_{0}^{s}(1 - f(u))du^k$.